# Bad interpreter Error while running python scripts

Tags: python, linux, flask

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path

db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

I use following command

```
chmod a+x db_create.py  
./db_create.py
```

but this gives me the error.
Does the comment on first line affect running script.
I have this file in this directory /home/Name/FlaskLearn/microblog/db_create.py

Comment: Try giving absolute path to flask (start with "/"). Something like: `#!/path/flask/bin/python`. Also, the first line might look like a comment, but its called: "Shebang." When you execute the script as ./somescript, then the the executable specified in the first line is executed with this file path as last parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang line is erroneous. You cannot use a relative path in the shebang (other than indirectly, via `#!/usr/bin/env flask/bin/python` or similar; I don't think that works as is, but you get the general idea).

Comment: thanks when i read about the shebang line i came to know about this error which i fixed it!